# SQL Server service not working for remote access

Tags: sql-server, timeout, connection-string

I am getting a timeout when connecting to my SQL Server. I can connect to it from the same machine (localhost) using trusted connection.

But now I need to connect to it from a remote computer.

- On SQL Server Configuration i see the port being used is 1032.
- Firewall rule on router set to send incoming on 1032 to the server:1032
- SQL Server is set to accept remote connections
- TCP/IP is on
- Username/Password is correct

I am using this way to create the ConnectionString:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
b.DataSource = "server.com\\SQLEXPRESS";
b.InitialCatalog = "OS";
b.IntegratedSecurity = false;
b.UserID = "sa";
b.Password = "CorrectPassword";
```

But i get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

For information purposes, here is the connection string I use from the localhost:

```
 @"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
```

Executing in server:

```
netstat -ano 
TCP 0.0.0.0:1032 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3788
```

If i use some website to check if the service can be seen, they all say that the port is closed.

What else should i try? Is the server port (1032) the only one needed to be open? I am trying for hours a simple thing like this shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: if it's a local machine, it could be portforwarding on the router

Comment: i am connecting to the server from a remote location. Port 1032 is open on router and forwarded to server.

Comment: Verify port connectivity remotely with this PowerShell command: `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('server.com', 1032)) "success"`

Comment: Also, to connect to a named instance without a port number specification, the SQL Server Browser service must be running and UDP port 1433 open. UDP traffic might be blocked.

Comment: How can i verify which port SQL Server Browser is running on? I opened that port on firewall, still same error. It's mind boggling....

Comment: use Server = `server.com,1032`